# How to compute the comparison ratio? while converting the CD audio into mp3 file at 96 Kbps.

Tags: compression, mp3

sample rate is 44.1kHZ
Bits per sample is 16
so BPS Will be  2*16*44100 which leads 1411.2 KBPS

Comment: Do you mean "compression ratio"?

Comment: Yes. what will be compression ration while doing this task?

Comment: Please edit your question with the corrected spelling, and accept an answer if it proves helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ratio is simply one quantity divided by another quantity, assuming both quantities are expressed in the same units.

CD audio does indeed provide two stereo 16-bit samples 44100 times per second, for a total of 1411200 bits per second.  This is accompanied on disk with a header, but this is usually very small compared to the audio data.

At 96 Kbps, an MP3-format compressed audio file can be assumed to use 96000 bits per second.

Dividing one by the other gives a compression ratio of 14.7:1.